# Magento 2 : Get Global Max Allowed Quantity

Tags: magento2.3, cart, quantity

How can I get global max sales qty in cart page.

[image: this value not in each product page]

Comment: Can you specify your requirement in more details what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get it :

```
$configValue = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::class)
            ->getValue('cataloginventory/item_options/max_sale_qty');
        
        echo "<pre>";print_r($configValue);die;
```